# Use a repeater to display images from image library

Tags: web-part

I am creating a sandboxed webpart which display a list from my SP.  I have the following code

ASCX page...

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCarousel" runat="server" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div>
                <div class="sliderstuff">
                    <asp:Image ID="imgCarousel" runat="server" />
                    <h2><asp:Literal ID="litTitle" runat="server" /></h2>
                    <h3><asp:Literal ID="litDescription" runat="server" /></h3>
                    <div class="btnSlider">
                        <a href="#" ><asp:Literal ID="litLinktext" runat="server" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Then my code behind

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Using site As New SPSite("http://cn-lap-hp-dev/")
        Using web As SPWeb = site.OpenWeb()
            Dim Imagelist As SPList = web.Lists("Home Page Carousel")

            rptCarousel.DataSource = Imagelist.Items.GetDataTable()
            rptCarousel.DataBind()


        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

and

```
 Protected Sub rptCarousel_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptCarousel.ItemDataBound
    Dim litTitle As Literal
    Dim item As SPListItem = DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, SPListItem)


    'Find and initialise our elements
    litTitle = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("hypCompetitionID"), Literal)

    'Now add this record to the datarow
    litTitle.Text = "Test"

End Sub
```

Pretty simple i think but I cannot get the webpart to work when deployed...if i remove the "Handles rptCarousel.ItemDataBound" the webpart renders but with no data??  Anyone any ideas?

S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there, I would use the following.

```
Protected Sub rptCarousel_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptCarousel.ItemDataBound
    Dim litTitle As Literal

    Dim drv As DataRowView
    'Now add this record to the datarow
    drv = DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)

    'Find and initialise our elements
    litTitle = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("litTitle"), Literal)

    'Now set our values
    litTitle.Text = drv("Title").ToString()


End Sub
```